# Are "GONE" views detrimental to performance?

Tags: android, layout, android-view

I'm making an app in which it might save me some time to
have a single layout for several activities, with some of the views set to GONE depending on which activity is being used.

I know that having a large number of views in a layout can lead to poor performance. If I had an activity with a large number of views, but a large portion of those views were to to GONE, would this activity still perform poorly. That is, do views that are set to GONE contribute to worsening performance? If yes, do they demand less processing power than VISIBLE or INVISIBLE views?

Thanks!

Comment: Those views will still need to be inflated and they will occupy memory but they will not be part of the measuring and layout process of a view hierarchy.

Comment: +1 to that, in addition - think about it, you're just modifying the visual aspect of it, visible or invisible, gone is practically the same by nature, just does not occupy "physical" space on the screen.

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using different layouts if some `Activities` will have a large number of the views `GONE`?

Comment: To be honest it was more hypothetical. The layouts don't differ much necessarily. I guess the main use I'd have (in this app) for a lot of GONE views was to annotate input forms to explain to the user why their input had failed. I just wanted to make my question clear.

Comment: @user2120647 Ok, its a good question I just wanted to make sure you weren't trying to make something harder than it needed to be.

Comment: Thanks. Probably not the case here, but I'm quite inexperienced so I'm undoubtedly making it hard for myself somewhere =)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First thing you should know about gone vs invisible:

- View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
- View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

> Thinking about the impact on measuring.
>   Which one is more efficient all depends on how frequently you are
>   changing the view's visibility.
>
> For example, if the view is not visible for a majority of the time,
>   making it GONE would probably be more efficient, because the system
>   would not be needlessly measuring and laying out your invisible view
>   whenever it needs to adjust other views on the screen.
>
> On the other hand, if the view changes between visible and invisible
>   frequently, you might get better performance from INVISIBLE as you
>   would potentially avoid an extra measure/layout on each transition.

Answer (score 20):

[Here is an interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673017/difference-between-foo-setvisibilityview-gone-and-parent-removeviewfoo). I was wondering the same thing as you, and the answer is that `View.GONE` consumes more memory than simply calling `removeView(view)` on the view. However, `GONE` views do consume less memory than `View.VISIBLE` since they do not need to be drawn.

The memory amounts compare like this:

`View.VISIBLE` > `View.GONE` > `removing the view from the container`

What I do is use `View.GONE` on views that don't consume a lot of memory (like a TextView) and use `parent.removeView(view)` on views that are a lot of memory (like a WebView);

Comment: What about clearing the memory consumer from the `View` and using `View.GONE`? In the case of the `WebView`, stop rendering HTML in it, or an `ImageView`, removing the image.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.