# RecyclerView header and footer

Tags: android, header, footer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

Maybe this question has been asked before, but I could not seem to find a precise answer or solution. I started using the RecyclerView, and I implemented it using the LinearLayoutManager. Now I want to add custom header and footer items, that differ from the rest of the items in my RecyclerView. The header and footer should not be sticky, I want them to scroll with the rest of the items. Can somebody point out some example how to do this or just share ideas. I will appreciate it very much. Thx

Comment: see int RecyclerView.Adapter.getItemViewType(int position)

Comment: Can u post some code example, I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: override that method,  for position == 0 return 0 for any other position return 1, now onCreateViewHolder will be called with two different viewTypes: 0 for header view and 1 for "nornal" view

Comment: see this answer it has an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/2127203

Comment: thx @hister, I will take a look at the example...

Comment: the example that @hister provided did the trick for me

Comment: @pskink This would work only for LinearLayoutManager, but what about GridLayoutManager ? I think it's better to use something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869312/set-span-for-items-in-gridlayoutmanager-using-spansizelookup

Comment: @androiddeveloper so use spans

Comment: @pskink I don't understand. The link I've given handles spans too, no? do you have a different idea?

Comment: @androiddeveloper if you have for example 3 columns in your grid then return 3 in getSpanSize for position 0 otherwise return 1

Comment: @pskink Yes. But it's still not quite like headers on ListViews, no? What happens if you wish to add swipeToRefresh, but it should show beneath the header itself (like on Google Now Launcher) ? Is it still possible?

Comment: @androiddeveloper i don't think i understand what you mean

Comment: @pskink Open Google Now Launcher, then go to the left (in the home screens). Now, swipe up to refresh. You will see that the progress bar that appears will be shown beneath the header.

Comment: @androiddeveloper it all depends how you will implement your RecyclerView.Adapter, it adapts your data model to a presentation view, so you can do whatever you want

Comment: @pskink I see. In fact, the swipe-to-refresh has changed its style. now it's just a rotating circle, and as far as I remember it also supports recyclerView...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 5.0 - Add header/footer to a RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview)

Comment: issue in remove product with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222410/recyclerview-with-footer-not-able-to-delete-last-item

Answer (score 55):

in your adapter add this class:

```
private class VIEW_TYPES {
        public static final int Header = 1;
        public static final int Normal = 2;
        public static final int Footer = 3;
}
```

then Override the following method like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(items.get(position).isHeader)
        return VIEW_TYPES.Header;
    else if(items.get(position).isFooter)
        return VIEW_TYPES.Footer;
    else
        return VIEW_TYPES.Normal;

}
```

Now in the onCreateViewHolder method inflate your layout based on the view type::

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View rowView;

    switch (i) {

        case VIEW_TYPES.Normal:
            rowView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, viewGroup, false);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPES.Header:
            rowView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, viewGroup, false);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPES.Footer:
            rowView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer, viewGroup, false);
            break;
        default:
            rowView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, viewGroup, false);
            break;
    }
    return new ViewHolder (rowView);
}
```

Now in the onBindViewHolder method bind your layout based on the view holder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch(viewType) {

            case VIEW_TYPES.Header: // handle row header
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPES.Footer: // handle row footer
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPES.Normal: // handle row item
                break;

        }

    }
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: I could implement the header fine but when I added the footer its getting inserted after the first item of the Recycler view though I specified the Footer attribute as "layout_alignParentBottom=true". Any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: Hi, header and footer are item too, so you have to add the header first (checking that it is in the first position) then add your items and finally in the last position add the footer

Comment: Thanks for this solution but can you tell me where is the methods name, "isHeader" and "isFooter" ? @Bronx

Comment: Hi @RonakJoshi isHeader and isFooter are not methods, they are variables you have in the items of your list.
For example you have a class named MyItem and the constructor is 
public MyItem(Object myObject, boolean isHeader, boolean isFooter)

Comment: Yes,Got it. Thanks @Bronx +1 for your solution.

Comment: I keep getting 'cannot resolve symbol .isHeader'. Also 'method call expected' for 'return new ViewHolder (rowView);' The solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi @bluemunch, check my previous answer to RonakJoshi, isHeader is a parameter you must have in your item class. This was an example, you can use whatever logic you want to choose which item is the header or the footer.

Comment: @Bronx  Adding the link to that your other answer will be nice though.

Comment: @Bronx or add the full code because I am still having the same issue santafebound is having.

Comment: seems promising. But need a  full code. as Such I'm using Kotlin and didn't find items.get(position).isHeader (isHeader)  property here.  As well I am looking to put "Load more" button at the footer. So on click event also need to handle somewhere. Please help!

Answer (score 32):

This is very easy with ItemDecorations and without modifying any other code:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HeaderDecoration(this,
                               recyclerView,  R.layout.test_header));
```

Reserve some space for drawing, inflate the layout you want drawn and draw it in the reserved space.

The code for the Decoration:

```
public class HeaderDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private View mLayout;

    public HeaderDecoration(final Context context, RecyclerView parent, @LayoutRes int resId) {
        // inflate and measure the layout
        mLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resId, parent, false);
        mLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
        // layout basically just gets drawn on the reserved space on top of the first view
        mLayout.layout(parent.getLeft(), 0, parent.getRight(), mLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
                c.save();
                final int height = mLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                final int top = view.getTop() - height;
                c.translate(0, top);
                mLayout.draw(c);
                c.restore();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.set(0, mLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), 0, 0);
        } else {
            outRect.setEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you add click handling in item decorator?
I have to add a button as header, its can be seen with your code but I am unable to add on click as findViewById return null

Comment: @chin87 ...since `mLayout` is a view - just add it to the view? Either add a getter or modify the constructor. (And it depends where you call findViewById...Since the view is neither attached to the recyclerView nor to the fragment)

Comment: How do you use it to add a footer? Will it also work when LinearLayoutManager is horizontal?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you would have to modify or adapt the code, this sample is more proof of concept. to use it as footer you would check for last item rather than `position == 0` and draw beneath instead of above, for using it horizontally, you would also need to adapt it, modifying the drawing for left/right instead of above

Comment: @DavidMedenjak That's too bad. Do you know perhaps of a repo that has them all? Are there any disadvantages of using your solution, other than the need of extra code for each header&footer for horizontal&vertical

Comment: @androiddeveloper The only real downside is, that it is just a decoration. You won't be able to add onClick to it. I don't know of any full implementations, but modifying the code for all 4 cases is not too hard. You can find the repo that I play around with including more samples at https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Why can't I add onClick to it? because it has no real view, as it only draws stuff? Is it a lot of changes to the current code? Maybe it's better to just add parameters to the decorator, instead of creating new, similar classes.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Also, suppose I want to remove the header at some point, will it have a nice animation like of normal items of the RecyclerView (when they have an id) ? Or will it just disappear right away?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you don't get any animation for free. you can use the childs alpha and translation to animate with the child, I wrote an article on that here: http://bleeding182.blogspot.com/2015/11/animations-and-decorations.html

Comment: @DavidMedenjak The article is about normal items. You mean the same holds for decorators too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105656/discussion-between-david-medenjak-and-android-developer).

Comment: Very helpful? but I faced of with another problem. I've added progress bar in header but it animates only when I move list or call notifydatasetchange()

Comment: @Dima Yes. This is not a classic View, it's just some drawing on top. If you change it you will have to find a way to invalidate it yourself and update the recyclerview. The main use case of the presented answer is to show some image or text as a header

Comment: I've attempted your answer but I can't get it to work. How simple is your `R.layout.test_header`? The layout I am attempting to add is a bit more complex. LinearLayout and stuff. Is this not possible?

Comment: @Andy it really depends. Try using a fixed height/width and see if that helps, maybe it can't be properly measured/layouted. But I'd try to keep it simple

Comment: I use a TextView as a footer layout and it makes no new lines, just draws single line textview which goes out of bounds

Comment: If someones looking for the footer version: https://gist.github.com/dreiklangdev/4b092eade09feb26bdf1c090fd2e5643

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder did you try wrap it in a e.g. frameLayout?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak This works fine but the layout inside the header is clipped right side

Answer (score 11):

If all you need is a blank header and footer, here is a very simple way to achieve this (written in Kotlin):

```
class HeaderFooterDecoration(private val headerHeight: Int, private val footerHeight: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val adapter = parent.adapter ?: return
        when (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)) {
            0 -> outRect.top = headerHeight
            adapter.itemCount - 1 -> outRect.bottom = footerHeight
            else -> outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Call it this way:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(HeaderFooterDecoration(headerHeightPx, footerHeightPx))
```

Comment: Not very often that I find the best solution way down here. Short Concise, readable, gets the job done. Full Marks Sean :D

Comment: A very good example with source code to create RecyclerView with header and footer https://www.loopwiki.com/ui-ux-design/recyclerview-with-header-and-footer-android-example/

Answer (score 9):

You can use this GitHub] library to add a Header or Footer to your `RecyclerView` in the simplest way possible.

You need to add the [**HFRecyclerView**](https://github.com/lopspower/HFRecyclerView) library in your project or you can also grab it from Gradle:

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:hfrecyclerview:1.0.0'
```

> This library is based on a work at [@hister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/1832221)

This is a result in image:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 9):

recyclerview:1.2.0 introduces **ConcatAdapter**

> ConcatAdapter is a new RecyclerView Adapter that can combine multiple adapters linearly.

### How to use ConcatAdapter?

add following dependency into your `build.gradle` file

```
androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04
```

Then, if you have multiple adapters, you can easily merge them using

```
  MyAdapter adapter1 = ...;
 AnotherAdapter adapter2 = ...;
 ConcatAdapter merged = new ConcatAdapter(adapter1, adapter2);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(merged);
```

For the sample above, ConcatAdapter will present items from adapter1 followed by adapter2.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) you can find the complete documentation.

Find complete working sample [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/blob/step1_mergeadapter/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelabs/paging/ui/SearchRepositoriesActivity.kt).

Read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) article for more info.

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c0540c10cc7ea5027d3fc3b22024de7e66c41a9d/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter.java) you can find the source code.

Answer (score 3):

here some header itemdecoration for recyclerview

withsome modification you can change to footer

```
public class HeaderItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private View customView;

public HeaderItemDecoration(View view) {
    this.customView = view;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
    customView.layout(parent.getLeft(), 0, parent.getRight(), customView.getMeasuredHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            c.save();
            final int height = customView.getMeasuredHeight();
            final int top = view.getTop() - height;
            c.translate(0, top);
            customView.draw(c);
            c.restore();
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
        customView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        outRect.set(0, customView.getMeasuredHeight(), 0, 0);
    } else {
        outRect.setEmpty();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code came out really handy, but I tried modifying it for footer by changing
parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0
to
parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount()
But it didn;t work. Well, it does work for any other position in between, but not the last one, could you suggest any changes?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Trunks! In my case I have added a simple header containing only a TextView in this way: `recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HeaderItemDecoration(aTextView), 0)`.

Comment: @AnuragBhalekar it's parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == (parent.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not to customize rv adapater.

Keep it as it as...in your rv item layout just add the footer with the layout and set the visisbilty gone.

Then when you reach the last item in adapter...make it visible.

and when you try this make sure you add this to your rv adapter.

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
           if(i==List.size()) // Last item in recycle view
           personViewHolder.tv_footer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);// Make footer visible now }

 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Do the same for Header. 
Here i==0 // first item of list

Easiest solution to me.

Comment: Okay, your approach is straightforward. But, isn't it a waste of memory to have the view as `View.GONE` for most of the time?

Comment: @Kathir...it is processed only when its visible in the screen area...other time it is treated and kept in background  as usual array of records to be shown..

Comment: Thank you @Raktim. I found a relevant question [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17883768/7551190) that. In short, it still takes up memory comparing to what not having that view would be consuming but it's better than `View.INVISIBLE`. Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17883749/7551190) to understand when to use `View.INVISIBLE` instead

Answer (score 2):

Click [here](https://github.com/u3breeze/android-RecyclerView-WithHeaderAndFooter).
I did a extension of RecyclerView.Adapter. Easy to add header and footer.

```
class HFAdapter extends HFRecyclerViewAdapter<String, HFAdapter.DataViewHolder>{

    public HFAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateDataItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.data_item, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindDataItemViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemTv.setText(getData().get(position));
    }

    class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView itemTv;
        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTv = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTv);
        }
    }
}

//add header
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, recyclerView, false);
hfAdapter.setHeaderView(headerView);
//add footer
View footerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer, recyclerView, false);
hfAdapter.setFooterView(footerView);

//remove
hfAdapter.removeHeader();
hfAdapter.removeFooter();
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Sectioned LinearView headings with GridView items in Recyclerview:-**

Check [SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/e81e126227f8a4bb339c)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One other way would be wrapping header and reyclerview in a **coordinatorlayout**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: i didn't find a way to create a footer yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter), it has the concept of "Sections", where which Section has a Header, Footer and Content (list of items). In your case you might only need one Section but you can have many:

[image]

#### 1) Create a custom Section class:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3" });

    public MySection() {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_footer,  R.layout.section_item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return myList.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(myList.get(position));
    }
}
```

#### 2) Create a custom ViewHolder for the items:

```
class MyItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView tvItem;

    public MyItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    }
}
```

#### 3) Set up your ReclyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

MySection mySection = new MySection();

// Add your Sections
sectionAdapter.addSection(mySection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be [GroupAdapter](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/GroupAdapter) is what you want.

A specialized RecyclerView.Adapter that presents data from a sequence of RecyclerView.Adapter. The sequence is static but each adapter can be presented in zero or more item views. The child adapter can use ViewType safely. In addition, we can addHeaderView or addFooterView like ListView.