# Set span for items in GridLayoutManager using SpanSizeLookup

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want to implement grid-like layout with section headers. Think of https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders

What I do now:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_HEADER:
                        return 1;
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                        return 2;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Now both regular items and headers have span size of 1. How do I solve this?

Comment: this implementation looks correct to me. Did you debug if your `mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)` is returning the correct value ?

Comment: "1" seems like a safer default value than "-1".

Comment: I am a newbie. For me, this link helped me [3 RecyclerView Infinite Scroll Examples](https://androidride.com/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scroll-example/)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The problem was that header should have span size of 2, and regular item should have span size of 1.
So correct implementations is:

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_HEADER:
                        return 2;
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: get span size method determines the  amount span width your cell is going to take not the number of col row should have !!

Comment: when spanning the first item, it's messing up the height of the next ones. It works on any other item. Any idea ?

Comment: @RonnyShibley any solution for the issue you stated above ... I am also facing the same issue,  first item after the header doesn't shows , others are all shown up as required

Comment: This is not woking.

Answer (score 46):

Header should have a span equal to the span count of the entire list.

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
           switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_HEADER:
                        return mLayoutManager.getSpanCount();
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
    }
});
```

Comment: How comes no one links to the actual documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup
Hence, this answer seems more accurate to me then the currently accepted one. Maybe create a const variable with the span count and use it for the `GridLayoutManager` constructor and in the `getSpanSize` method to avoid the `getSpanCount` call for every header.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to my own question:
Override the getSpanSizeLookup() from the Activity after setting the adapter.