# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager with full width header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using a very helpful example [here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html) to show a RecyclerView and a GridLayoutManager to show a grid with a header.

It looks pretty good, but my graphic designer wants the header item to take up the full width of the RecyclerView. Right now there is padding.

When I set up the GridLayoutManager I add in padding (which I still want for the other grid items): [it's using Xamarin C#]

```
var numColumns = myListView.MeasuredWidth / tileSizeMax;
myGridView.SetPadding(tilePadding, tilePadding, tilePadding, tilePadding);
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Activity, numColumns);
myListView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

So, how can I set the padding to be different for the header item...or make it draw itself over the padding?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try with this:

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.HEADER:
                        return 2;

                    case MyAdapter.ITEM:
                    default:
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

And check these links:

- [RecyclerView: Grid with header](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)
- [Set span for items in GridLayoutManager using SpanSizeLookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869312/set-span-for-items-in-gridlayoutmanager-using-spansizelookup)

Comment: how to handle item decorator for last item?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Comment: @Kenji as a hint, you can check: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1895752 it has a view reference, you have its position, so you can modify it using some of your ideas ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

```
val spanSize = 2
val mLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(yourContext, spanSize)
mLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int = when (position) {
        0 -> spanSize
        else -> 1
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.