# Android:getting number of views in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, onscroll

I am implementing recyclerview with multiple layouts.Usually we have multiple viewholders for different layouts and override other methods as per the required layout.I have successfully implemented this.But now i have a different scenario like: A recyclerview that shows some videos (say 3) then another layout(say layout x), again 3 videos and then again layout x and so on.Suppose i have 10 videos then in this case the itemcount would be 10 + 3 as 3 layout x would be displayed.But the videos are loaded while scrolling.So how can i determine the number of views to return in getItemCount();
I mean

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

      return ListofVideos.size() + "WHAT??"
}
```

layout is like this
[image]

If all the videos are loaded at at once then it is easy to calculate the number of views like if i have 21 videos i would have total 27 views(i.e 21 videos and 6 layout X views). But when the list is loaded on scroll how can i determine the number of views?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Adapter` is responsible to populate view so it has all views of your `RecyclerView` while your `ListofVideos` (may) have only video links.

Whenever you scroll your `RecyclerView`, `Adapter` is responsible to inflate views.

**What you should do?**

Create an interface

```
public interface BaseItem {

    int ITEM_TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    int ITEM_TYPE_SUB_HEADER = 1;
    int ITEM_TYPE_ROW_NORMAL = 2;

    int getItemType();
}
```

And implement this interface with your adapter's video item like

```
public class YourAdapterVideoItem implements BaseItem {
  
   // rest of your code

   @Override
   public int getItemType() {
       return ITEM_TYPE_ROW_NORMAL;
   }
}
```

Create your adapter's header item

```
public class YourAdapterHeaderItem  implements BaseItem {

    // rest of your code

    @Override
    public int getItemType() {
        return ITEM_TYPE_HEADER;
    }
}
```

Update your adapter with

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   private List<BaseItem> items = new ArrayList<BaseItem>();
   
   @Override
    public BaseRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        BaseRecyclerViewHolder holder;
        switch (viewType) {
            case BaseItem.ITEM_TYPE_ROW_NORMAL:
            default:
                // inflate your default items
                break;
            case BaseItem.ITEM_TYPE_HEADER:
                // inflate your default items
                break;
        }
        return holder;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseRecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        BaseItem base = getItemAt(position);
        switch (base.getItemType()) {
            case BaseItem.ITEM_TYPE_HEADER:
                // populate your header view
                break;
            case BaseItem.ITEM_TYPE_ROW_NORMAL:
                // populate your actual view
                break;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items == null ? 0 : items.size();
    }

   @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItemAt(position).getItemType();
    }
    
    public BaseItem getItemAt(int position) {
        return items == null ? null : items.get(position);
    }
}
```

When you want to add header use `YourAdapterHeaderItem` for your videos use `YourAdapterVideoItem`.

Hope this helps

**Edit**

For adding headers in `GridLayoutManager` have a look at [RecyclerView GridLayoutManager with full width header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642869/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-with-full-width-header)