# Items with variable width on GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image: I'm trying to achieve this]

I'm trying to achieve this using a GridLayoutManager, It's possible to set the span size using a lookup, but I can't find a way to set the span to something like wrap_content.

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869312/set-span-for-items-in-gridlayoutmanager-using-spansizelookup) solve the problem if you know before hand the size but not when it's dynamic like on this image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like a FlowLayout. There are a number of implementations on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20flow%20layout)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout. I could not figure out how to centre but it's closer to the final result I want to achive.