# How to make first row in reycle view Gridlayout and other recycle Linearlayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, recycle

i want to make Recycle view contain grid and linear manager i tried to use this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869312/set-span-for-items-in-gridlayoutmanager-using-spansizelookup) but it not work with me

[image: Like this image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to do this:

- use a grid layout manager, and for items on rows 2 onward you use a cell span of 2, so each item occupies the whole row (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html)
- use 2 different view types, 1 for the first row containing 2 children, and then a different view type for all the other items (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int))