# How to implement a recycler view in Kotlin that can handle cells of different sizes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm a swift developer and I was able to build this layout very easily using a UICollectionView. However, I'm struggling to do the same in Kotlin. I've been trying to use a Recycler View to do this but it's[image] not working out. Any advice on how I can do this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post what have you done so far and it's result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with a few suggestions as to how I would be making this layout. Check if it's of any help:

First, follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) for implementing multiple viewtypes in your recyclerview by overriding `getItemViewType()` method in your recyclerview adapter. You can set the item's viewtype based on its position in the datalist or a value in your datasource etc. Based on this viewtype returned you can set what your viewholder should look like in the adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` and the funtionality in `onBindViewHolder()` method.

Next your recyclerview will need to make use of a `GridLayoutManager` with vertical orientation and 2 columns.

With these 2 steps you can have multiple views in different columns as you require, BUT in order to have a viewholder occupy whole width like the 2nd row in your sample image you will need to make use of `setSpanSizeLookup()` method of your grid layout manager. You can use [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869312/set-span-for-items-in-gridlayoutmanager-using-spansizelookup) for reference.

Basically this is all you need to achieve your layout. Make use of multiple viewtypes for recyclerview with a gridlayout manager having a custom spansize lookup.

The references i mentioned are mostly in java but converting them to kotlin should be fairly easy. Have a look and let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this amazing reply. You really helped me out, especially with the second link. I'm using Groupie to make things easier and with setSpanSizeLookUp() I was able to do what I needed.