# android recyclerview load more button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a tutorial/example to include a load more button with recyclerview? 
 I need to add a button after displaying 8  elements in the recyclerview.  The user can click this button to load the next 8 contents.

Comment: your question is not much clear...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a footer view to your recyclerview which includes Load More button. When clicking the button, make a request for next 8 items. After loading items, notify the adapter.

[RecyclerView header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585941/recyclerview-header-and-footer)

Comment: @SoliQuiD please remove your downvote, The answer is valid because Approved by OP. And its not a wrong answer, just you get it wrong, it doesn't means its not valid. I said "Add a footer view to your recycleview..." I did not say addFooterView() etc. Additionally, edited my answer for the users like you.

Comment: your answer didn't make sense before editing it to include the new answer link. I will remove the downvote now, since the answer at least points to the right answer

Answer (score 2):

what you need is endless recycler view ,which will load the data while scrolling . Here I have attached link for that implementation.

[Follow this link](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)