# Adjust content to scrollable row width in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row with an horizontal scroll and `n` items inside of varying and unknown widths.

Case 1 -> In case the items dont fill the container's width I want the last item to fill the remaining space.

Case 2 -> In case the items sum of widths is higher than the containers width (hence allowing scroll), I want the last item to behave like all the others.

I have tried to use `.fillMaxWidth` in the last item but inside a scrollable row this has zero effect.

I can use `.weight(1f)` for Case 1, but this ruins the UI in Case 2.

I know a solution could be calculating manually the width of each item, and switch the modifier from adding the weight modifier to not using it as soon as the widths exceed the container's width but I believe there might be a solution using Modifier functions inside the Row? Or possibly with a Lazy Row?

Sample code:

```
val horizontalScroll = rememberScrollState()
    Row(
      Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .horizontalScroll(horizontalScroll)
    ) {
      items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        ItemComponent(
          modifier = if (index == items.lastIndex) Modifier.weight(1f) else Modifier
          text = item.text
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72936954/make-last-item-of-the-compose-lazycolumn-fill-rest-of-the-screen