# Place RecyclerViewItem at bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which fits the whole screen.
The last item should always be positioned at the of the end screen, how can I do this? 
+--------+
|   Item1     |
|   Item2    |
|                |
|                |
|   Item3   |
+--------+

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253811/make-last-item-viewholder-in-recyclerview-fill-rest-of-the-screen-or-have-a-mi

Comment: I need more details, let me see your code.

Comment: Thank you. Item decoration is the way I chose.