# How can I show a button under the recyclerview like a footer but without disappearing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, footer

I want to create a footer-like button under the recyclerview. But the footer appears under the last element of recyclerview. I want my button to appear as an item at the bottom when it is a short list, and as a view at the bottom of the recyclerview in a long list. I explained the situation visually at image below [image: link]

How can I do this, does it have a known name or do I need to use floating action buttons, etc?

Comment: Have you tried any of this solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890709/how-implement-sticky-footer-in-recyclerview

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez This solution does not meet state 1. But good to know the name sticky footer, looks like I can move forward from here, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, let us know if you need anything.