# Showing different Footer layouts in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to know what is the right way to implement a footer in RecyclerView which can be used to display different views. Few examples are as below

- View for network error with a button to reload.
- View when data is loading from server with a progress bar.
- View when there is no more data available.
- And so on.

I came across https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168617/371557 which mentions that I have to Override getItemViewType and inflate different views in onCreateViewHolder

What I do not understand is how will RecyclerView know which ViewType it has to request for? How can I force the RecyclerView to show the ViewType?

Comment: Check this out - http://takeoffandroid.com/android-customview/header-and-footer-layout-for-recylerview/

Comment: That link helped me to understand how to display header and footer. But I still did not understand how to force RecyclerView to show different footer view based on few conditions.

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerView is the new view more powerfull than listview, you can make a footer in this but it's for me not the right way.
I recommend to create a **layout** include your RecyclerView and add a dedicated view like **Snackbar** or a custom footer.

For your question, the RecyclerView knows what to display with the `getItemViewType(int positionItem)` method.

For example, if the item in position 6 must be shown in the list, *getItemViewType* return the id of view in `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int id)` method and recycle the view which could already be used in list for saving memory.

(Sorry for my poor English :)